# is it necessary to migarte the images from Container Registry to Artifact Registry

Tags: deprecated, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

is it necessary to migarte the images from Container Registry to Artifact Registry as Container Registry is getting end of support by MAy 2024 or "gcr.io" will automatucally be re-directed?

want to know, images stored in Container Registry currently are to be migarted Artifact Registry post? or Google will take care of the migration

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended to migrate from GCR->AR. There will likely be additional tooling soon to make this migration easier.

In 2024, you will stop being able to use GCR in projects that haven't used GCR previously. You will still be able to create gcr.io repos, they will just use AR.